# How to close Child Dialog Window from Another Apps in MFC

Tags: mfc, dialog, postmessage, childwindow

I'm trying to Closing the Specific App's child dialog window from another MFC applications. `PostMessage` / `SendMessage` does not work even if i get the child `HWND`. any thought? thanks in advance.

Cheers

Comment: Why does your application need to do that? What makes it more special than the application you are trying to hijack, or, say, the user?

Comment: What messages did you post / send? Could you show some code?